# SharePoint 2010 error when importing excel spreadsheet to sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel

I get the following error when trying to import an excel spreadsheet into a SharePoint list.

```
"The specified file is not a valid spreadsheet or contains no data to import"
```

I have added this site to “Trusted Sites” list in the IE 8 but this does nothing.

Setup: I am using Excel 2010, Windows 7, IE 8, SharePoint Server 2010 which are all loaded on a Windows 7 laptop.

I followed these directions for importing a spreadsheet as a list: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/import-a-spreadsheet-as-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: Is the problem just on your computer and whether did you tried it in any other browser and if it works then ?

Comment: I installed SharePoint Server 2010 on my Windows 7 laptop and everything is being run locally browser IE 8 accessing sharepoint site all on my laptop.

Comment: Does this happen with all spreadsheets or just this one?

Comment: It is happening with all spreadsheets.  I followed these directions:  http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/import-a-spreadsheet-as-a-list-in-sharepoint-2010.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I searched some more and found the solution (thanks to SunnyLowe)

The real problem here is **Internet Explorer (IE)**.

1. In IE, from the File menu or Tools Icon, select Internet Options|Security Tab
2. In the "Select a zone to view... ", click **Trusted Sites** so it is highlighted. Then click  **Sites** to add the site to your trusted sites list.
   Tab. (This was already automatically done for me).
3. Set the **Security level for this zone** of the **Trusted sites** to **Low**.
4. Then reload the webpage, and it should load fine.

I had only checked # 2 and didn't see mention of# 3 of above until I found SunnyLowe's post here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointadmin/thread/27279fd1-d3c5-4986-9810-416b294aec49

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when required field "Title" was hidden in the list and I did not insert data from EXCEL to that column.

Try to check out if there are columns in the list which are not in the excel. Try to copy column one by one...

Should be one or more column missing.

Hope it helps,

Andrew